# Proper way of testing ASP.NET Core IMemoryCache

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, moq, extension-methods, .net-core

I'm writing a simple test case that tests that my controller calls the cache before calling my service. I'm using xUnit and Moq for the task.

I'm facing an issue because `GetOrCreateAsync<T>` is an extension method, and those can't be mocked by the framework. I relied on internal details to figure out I can mock `TryGetValue` instead and get away with my test (see https://github.com/aspnet/Caching/blob/c432e5827e4505c05ac7ad8ef1e3bc6bf784520b/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions/MemoryCacheExtensions.cs#L116)

```
[Theory, AutoDataMoq]
public async Task GivenPopulatedCacheDoesntCallService(
    Mock<IMemoryCache> cache,
    SearchRequestViewModel input,
    MyViewModel expected)
{
    object expectedOut = expected;
    cache
        .Setup(s => s.TryGetValue(input.Serialized(), out expectedOut))
        .Returns(true);
    var sut = new MyController(cache.Object, Mock.Of<ISearchService>());
    var actual = await sut.Search(input);
    Assert.Same(expected, actual);
}
```

I can't sleep with the fact that I'm peeking into the MemoryCache implementation details and it can change at any point.

For reference, this is the SUT code:

```
public async Task<MyViewModel> Search(SearchRequestViewModel request)
{
    return await cache.GetOrCreateAsync(request.Serialized(), (e) => search.FindAsync(request));
}
```

Would you recommend testing any differently?

Comment: You shouldn't test `IMemoryCache` since it is part of a library. The authors of the library should do the testing.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

To be honest I would recommend not to test this interaction at all.

I would approach this test case a bit differently: what you really care about is that once your controller retrieved data from your `ISearchService` it shouldn't request the data again and should return the result from the previous call.

The fact that an `IMemoryCache` is used behind the scenes is just an implementation detail. I wouldn't even bother setting up a test double for it, I would just use an instance of the `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.MemoryCache` object.

My new test would look something like this:

```
[Theory]
public async Task GivenResultAlreadyRetrieved_ShouldNotCallServiceAgain()
{
    // Arrange
    var expected = new MyViewModel();

    var cache = new MemoryCache(new MemoryCacheOptions());
    var searchService = new Mock<ISearchService>();

    var input = new SearchRequestViewModel();

    searchService
        .SetupSequence(s => s.FindAsync(It.IsAny<SearchRequestViewModel>()))
        .Returns(Task.FromResult(expected))
        .Returns(Task.FromResult(new MyViewModel()));

    var sut = new MyController(cache, searchService.Object);

    // Act
    var resultFromFirstCall = await sut.Search(input);
    var resultFromSecondCall = await sut.Search(input);

    // Assert
    Assert.Same(expected, resultFromFirstCall);
    Assert.Same(expected, resultFromSecondCall);
}
```

Comment: I like your approach a lot more. Thanks!