# Problem in casting Generic.List to System.Threading.Task.Generic.List

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core, moq, xunit

I am trying to create mock of `IMemoryCache.TryGetValue` method but it returns the following error when it hit `cache.Get(cacheKey)`:

> Unable to cast object of type `` 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ConnectionsModel]' to type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ConnectionsModel] ``

Here is the mock:

```
 private static Mock<IMemoryCache> ConfigureMockCacheWithDataInCache(List<ConnectionsModel> auth0ConnectionsResponse)
 {
        object value = auth0ConnectionsResponse;
        var mockCache = new Mock<IMemoryCache>();
        mockCache
            .Setup(x => x.TryGetValue(
                It.IsAny<object>(), out value
            ))
            .Returns(true);
        return mockCache;
    }
```

Here is the test method:

```
var connectionList = new List<ConnectionsModel>();
var connectionsModel= new ConnectionsModel()
{
     id = "1",
    name = "abc",
    enabled_cons = new List<string>() { "test" }
};
connectionList.Add(connectionsModel);
var mockObject = ConfigureMockCacheWithDataInCache(connectionList);
var sut = new MyService(mockCache.Object);
// Act
var result = await sut.GetConnection(_clientId);
```

and here is the service that it hits:

```
public async Task<ConnectionsModel> GetConnection(string clientId)
{
    var connections = await _cacheService.GetOrSet("cacheKey", ()=> CallBack());
    var connection = connections.FirstOrDefault();
    return connection;
}
private async Task<List<ConnectionsModel>> CallBack()
{
    string url = url;
    _httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(BaseUrl);
    var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(url);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<ConnectionsModel>>();
}
```

and the cache extension method:

```
   public static T GetOrSet<T>(this IMemoryCache cache, string cacheKey, Func<T> getItemCallback, double cacheTimeout = 86000) where T : class
    {
        T item = cache.Get<T>(cacheKey);
        if (item == null)
        {
            item = getItemCallback();
            cache.Set(cacheKey, item, DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(cacheTimeout));
        }
        return item;
    }
```

After this line `T item = cache.Get<T>(cacheKey);` I am getting the above mentioned exception. How can I fix this?

Comment: somewhere you are passing in a Task and trying to assign it to the result of the task. Recheck the logic for your extension method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider creating an additional overload of the extension to allow for asynchronous API to be used

```
public static async Task<T> GetOrSet<T>(this IMemoryCache cache, string cacheKey, Func<Task<T>> getItemCallback, double cacheTimeout = 86000) where T : class
{
    T item = cache.Get<T>(cacheKey);
    if (item == null)
    {
        item = await getItemCallback();
        cache.Set(cacheKey, item, DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(cacheTimeout));
    }
    return item;
}
```

Comment: Also I have written a mock for this extension method based on your other answer. Is this fine?      
   
            object expected;
            var mockCache = new Mock<IMemoryCache>();
            var cachEntry = Mock.Of<ICacheEntry>();
            mockCache
                .Setup(x => x.TryGetValue(
                    It.IsAny<object>(), out expected
                ))
                .Returns(true);
            mockCache
                .Setup(x => x.CreateEntry(
                It.IsAny<object>()
             ))
          .Returns(cachEntry);
           return mockCache;

Comment: @Ask looks Ok at initial glance. Does it work for your test?

Answer (score 1):

In your extension method, you're calling `getItemCallback()` without awaiting it. That lambda calls your `Callback` method in your service which is async, so this is async as well. As a result, you're setting `item` to `Task<List<ConnectionsModel>>` and trying to return that as a `List<ConnectionsModel>`.

```
item = await getItemCallback();
```

Comment: but since the extension is not async it would need to be refactored.

Comment: how can I change Func<T> getItemCallBack(0 in param to be awaitable?

Comment: You shouldn't need to. The return value will be a `Task`, which is always awaitable. However, you can also try passing an async lambda `async () => await Callback()`

Comment: I had tried async () => await Callback() but had same results

Comment: Also, @Nkosi is correct. If you have an async operation, you have to go async all the way. That means your extension method should be async and anything that calls it will need to be async as well.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to convert it to async but I am not sure how can I make getItemCallback() awaitable which is passed in param

Comment: Not sure what your exact issue is. `getItemCallback` currently is returning a `Task`. `Task`s are awaitable. You don't have to do *anything*.

Comment: @ChrisPratt is OK if I add the comment you made about making the extension async to you answer to make it complete?